# Rescaling Image in Windows Form

Tags: c#, math, rescale

I have a set of points I want to show on a 2000x2000 canvas.  Here is an example: "61.86, 83 - 61.79, 82.91 - 61.77, 82.77 - 61.92, 82.76 - 61.75, 82.7 - 61.79, 82.58 - 61.85, 82.46 - 61.79, 82.17 - 61.72, 81.88 - 61.61, 81.61 - 61.51, 81.33 - 61.49, 81.02 - 61.33, 80.99 - 61.37, 80.83"

These points are from a 100x100 grid so the first one ought to be in the bottom right quarter of my 2000*2000 canvas.

To do this I have code that finds the biggest X and Y and then rescales.

```
        List<double> MinAndMax(List<Node> spots)
        {
            List<double> retValues = new List<double>();
            double xLowest = spots.Select(s => s.X).Min();
            double xHighest = spots.Select(s => s.X).Max();
            double xDifference = xHighest - xLowest;
            double yLowest = spots.Select(s => s.Y).Min();
            double yHighest = spots.Select(s => s.Y).Max();
            double yDifference = yHighest - yLowest;
            if (xLowest < yLowest)
                retValues.Add(xLowest);
            else
                retValues.Add(yLowest);

            if (xHighest < yHighest)
                retValues.Add(yHighest);
            else
                retValues.Add(xHighest);

            return retValues;
        }
        int Rescale(double oldValue, double oldMin, double oldMax, int newMin, int newMax)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(((oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMin);
        }
```

I call it like so:

```
            double zoneMin, zoneMax;
            int lowestCanvas = 150, highestCanvas = 1850;

            List<Node> path = await PathMaker();
            List<double> zoneMinMax = MinAndMax(path);

            zoneMin = zoneMinMax[0];
            zoneMax = zoneMinMax[1];

            foreach (Node spot in path)
            {
                Point point = new Point();
                point.X = Rescale(spot.X, zoneMin, zoneMax, lowestCanvas, highestCanvas);
                point.Y = Rescale(spot.Y, zoneMin, zoneMax, lowestCanvas, highestCanvas);
                NodeSpot dot = new NodeSpot()
                {
                    Name = spot.Name,
                    Location = point,
                    IsInPath = true
                };
                drawingSurface1.Nodes.Add(dot);
            }
            drawingSurface1.Invalidate();
```

Instead of getting my little path nicely spread out, I get this odd clump in the bottom LEFT had quadrant.
[image: You can see the clump]

I can't see where I am going wrong here. What do I need to do in order to have my 14 points spread out over the canvass?

Comment: Can you also create an image which would show where the points should have been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are returning a single min value and a single max value. You need separate min and max values for X and Y, as the ranges in each coordinate are different. In your sample data from the question the range of X is [-61.92, 61.86] and the range of Y is [80.83, 83]. Your approach will draw a frame covering [-61.92, -61.92] to [83, 83], with most of the points in one corner.

Your test fails to catch the problem as the X and Y values are the same in the test case. Create a test case where the X values are all negative and the Y values positive, this will show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

let's take [[20, 20], [50, 50], [80, 80]] as an easy exemple.

min and max will be 20 and 80 and wanted scale is 0 to 2000.

for the point [50, 50]

```
(((oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMin)
```

gives

```
((50 - 20) * (2000 - 0) / (80 - 20)) + 0
= 30*2000 / 60
= 1000 (which is half the size of the canvas)
```

seems coherent so the problem is not coming from the transform function

**I suggest trying to debug it by printing the [X, Y] values of the "point" to be sure tho**

**Also print the min max of the oldScale to be sure this is not the problem**

Comment: The points I am failing with are "61.86, 83 - 61.79, 82.91 - 61.77, 82.77 - 61.92, 82.76 - 61.75, 82.7 - 61.79, 82.58 - 61.85, 82.46 - 61.79, 82.17 - 61.72, 81.88 - 61.61, 81.61 - 61.51, 81.33 - 61.49, 81.02 - 61.33, 80.99 - 61.37, 80.83"

I tried to change them like so: 
int a = 10;
foreach (Node node in path)
{
    node.X = a;
    node.Y = a;
    a += 50;
}

This generated a perfect line across the drawing canvas.  I can't see why that list of 14 points isn't also spreading across the canvas.

Comment: you should get used to doing tests, so you can have easy values to work with and find the problem fast

Comment: The points are transformed to "96, 1950 - 90, 1942 - 89, 1930 - 102, 1929 - 87, 1924 - 90, 1913 - 96, 1903 - 90, 1877 - 84, 1852 - 75, 1828 - 66, 1804 - 64, 1776 - 50, 1774 - 54, 1760" if that helps.

Comment: yeah I lot, because it tells us that it get printed on your canvas from ~50 to ~100 on the X axis and from ~1750 to ~1950 on the Y axis. your problem is comming from the MinandMax() function could you print the output of it?

Comment: zoneMin = 61.33 and zoneMax = 83.  The MinAndMax code is exactly as in my question.

Comment: Ignore the comment I delete please - that was a stupid error on my part.  int a = 10; foreach (Node node in path) { node.X = a; node.Y = a; a += 5; } produces a perfect graph which makes it all the more maddening that the "real" numbers jsut produce a clump in one quadrant.

Comment: Has anyone any suuggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: your problem may come from double/float to integer convertion, Let me know when you've done testing this possible issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Graphics.PageScale Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.pagescale?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-graphics-pagescale)

See also [Coordinate Systems and Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/coordinate-systems-and-transformations?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)